# Getting an error in GEB+Spock+ Groovy

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

I am new to GEB + Spock and trying to use this in our project. I have the following installed :

```
GEB- geb-core-0.7.0.jar
SPOCK- Spock core-0.7 - groovy 2.0
GROOVY- Groovy1.8.9
```

Below is my code which contains method.

```
package projectGEB

import javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement; 
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.Variable;
import geb.*
import groovy.model.ValueHolder;
import spock.lang.*
import geb.spock.*

class GoogleSearchModule extends Module {
class Google extends Page {
    static url = "http://www.google.co.in/"
    static at = { title == "Google" }
     static content = {
        searchField { $("input[name=q]") }
        searchButton{ $("input[value=Google Search]") }
    }

    }

}
```

Below is the calling method*/

```
package projectGEB

import spock.lang.Specification
import geb.*
import grails.plugin.geb.*
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver


class DemoClass extends Specification {

def "HelloProgram"(){
    expect:
    Browser.drive(new Browser(driver: new FirefoxDriver())) {

        to Google
        println "Hello"
    }.quit()
}
}
```

I'm getting underlined $ sign. Is this an error? How do I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0` with groovy 1.8.9? That's for groovy 2

Comment: can you show your error message?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are nesting a page in a module? Normally pages can contain modules, but I don't think the opposite is possible by design.

In this case you should remove the Module wrapping your page, and use the page as is.

Modules are handy when you have pieces of content that are reused in many pages, here is a simple example of how one would use a module:

```
class MessagesModule extends Module {

  static content = {
    errorMessage { i -> $(".errors").find("li")[i] }
    flashMessage { $(".message") }
  }

}
```

This module is then easily used in page objects like so:

```
class GroupsPage extends Page {

  static url = "group"

  static at = {
    $("h1").text() == "Groups"
    $("h2").text() == "Select a group"
  }

  static content = {
    groupEmail { $("input[name=email]") }
    createGroup { $("#createGroup") }
    searchGroup { $("#searchGroup") }
    messages { module MessagesModule }
  }

}
```

You can then write a simple test using spock and geb:

```
 def "search non-existing group"() {

   given: "I am on the groups page"
    to GroupsPage

   when: "I look for a non existing group"
    page.groupEmail = "non-existing@group.com"
    page.searchGroup.click()

   then: "I remain on that page, there is an info message"
    at GroupsPage
    page.messages.flashMessage.text() == "No group found"
}
```